# IE 7 display problem with 2 wrappers

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have 2 wrappers, one inside the other, as per html below.  The first wrapper contains a tile which scrolls down.  Wrapper 2 has an image 940 X295px.  Works beautifully in IE5 & IE8, but in IE7 the footer jumps up to wrapper2  and the text extends down, underneath and below.

This is my html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="wrapper2">
<div id="maincontent"></div>
<div id="navigation"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

I have moved the closing div's everwhere with no success.

My css for the above divs are:

```
body {
 margin-top: 0px;
 padding-top: 0px;
 background-image: url(../images/body_vert_tile.gif);
 background-color: #C8BE86;
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
#wrapper {
 background-attachment: scroll;
 background-image: url(../images/wrapper_horiz_tile.gif);
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 width: 940px;
}
#wrapper2 {
 background-image: url(../images/wrapper_2.jpg);
 height: 295px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 background-position: left top;
}
#header {
 width: 940px;
 background-image: url(../images/header.jpg);
 height: 345px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
}
#maincontent {
 float: right;
 width: 630px;
 padding-right: 70px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 margin-top: -10px;
}
#maincontent_home {
 float: right;
 width: 420px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 margin-top: -10px;
}
#secondary_content {
 float: right;
 width: 190px;
 padding-right: 70px;
 margin-top: 30px;
 padding-left: 20px;
}
#footer {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: left bottom;
 width: 940px;
 text-align: center;
 clear: right;
 background-image: url(../images/footer.jpg);
 height: 145px;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
#navigation {
 float: right;
 width: 130px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 background-position: right top;
 padding-top: 5px;
}
```

I'm pulling my hair out.  Should I just ignore IE7?  I'd really like to overcome this.  The only way around this I have found is to have wrapper 2 sit below the header and close before the main content.  I then set -ve margins at the top of the content and nav the same size as the height of the image in wrapper2.  It worked, but i don't know if I should be doing things like this.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could provide an URL to check this behavior, but i would add a :

```
<div style="clear:both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

after the closing of the navigation DIV

BTW, I your are not using any CSS reset, you should. I use blueprint, but there are many.

Comment: Alejandro I don't think it worked.  But my only means of testing is in IE8 and clicking on compatibility mode.

Answer (score 0):

Alejandro suggested I remove the height of Wrapper 2 and add: background repeat: no repeat;

When I did this the image disappeared, but when I changed the height property to min:height: 295px; it worked beautifully.  Thankyou Alejandro for pointing me in the right direction